# Visual studio 2019 Android - unexpected element <uses-permission> found in <manifest><application>

Tags: android, xamarin

I am getting this error when I hit build solution or build project in Visual Studio 2019 Android (Xamarin). What can I do to fix this?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I expect it to build. Instead, I get:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       unexpected element <uses-permission> found in <manifest><application>.  DeepSound   D:\ProjectFolder\ProjectName\obj\Debug\90\android\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml  41
```

Full manifest file: https://pastebin.com/wwrkuCMK

Comment: Can you post your manifest file ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wwrkuCMK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error indicates that you have put your permissions inside of the `<Application>` tag. They should be outside in the root `<manifest>`. Remove them and it will get happy again.

Answer (score 2):

App permissions should be under `<manifest>` and not `<Application>`

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra set of following in line number 41 in pastebin which is causing the issue.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I tried deleting them but the manifest re-generates them automatically. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried disabling the permissions from the Android manifest in project properties but they still re-generate.

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
android:maxSdkVersion="28"
```

to the lines and it worked.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:maxSdkVersion="28"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="28"/>
```